# Play a video full screen without control at startup screen

Tags: ipad, video, fullscreen, playback

I am creating an iPad app, I want to play a video fullscreen without control at startup screen when app is loading data, I searched and found some article about MPPlayerViewController, I used it but I have some issue as below:

- I use below code to play video:

> ```
> NSString *moviePath = [ [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StartupVideo.mp4"];
>     moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:moviePath]];
>     moviePlayerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
>
>     [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerViewController.view];
>     [self.view sendSubviewToBack:moviePlayerViewController.view];
>
>     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
>                                                  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
>                                                object:[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer]];
>
>     MPMoviePlayerController *player = [moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer];
>     player.fullscreen = YES;
>     player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
>     player.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;
>     [player play];
> ```

Everything seems right but the video is not loaded, I only see a black screen.

- How can I hide controls in the MPVideoPlayerView?

Answer (score 0):

instead of
    `[NSURL URLWithString:moviePath]`

use

```
[NSURL fileURLWithString:moviePath]
```

got me so many times.. :)